# Rails Issues with association between User and Contact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Initially started with Contacts, as expected created a list of populated contacts which correctly allow CRUD. Then set up the login with devise which created Users. When logging in as two different users each should only see their own contacts however currently users sees all the same contacts.

Any help resolving this issue would be appreciated?

(Not sure if should have started with User and then created Contact, feels like this is created backwards.)

Understanding for associations is User 'has_many :contacts' and Contacts 'belongs_to :users' have been changing and spiking to no avail.

ContactsController

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :contact, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]   before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all   end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new   end

  def create
    Contact.create(contact_params)
    redirect_to '/contacts'   end

  def show   end

  def edit   end

  def update
    @contact.update(contact_params)
    redirect_to '/contacts/' + "#{@contact[:id]}"   end


  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    redirect_to '/contacts'   end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :surname, :email, :phone, :image)   end``

  def contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])   end


end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 end

model Contact
 class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :users

   has_attached_file :image, styles: {thumb: "100x100>"}  
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type:
 /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

 end
```

model user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  end
```

indexhtml

```
<%if user_signed_in? %>   <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %> <%end%>

<% if @contacts.any? %>   <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>   <%= link_to image_tag(contact.image.url(:thumb)), contact_path(contact) %> <h3><%= contact.firstname%> <%=contact.surname%></h3>   <%=contact.email%><br />   <%=contact.phone%>   <br />   <br />   <%end%> <%else%>   No contacts yet! <%end%> <br /> <br /> <%= link_to 'Add a contact', new_contact_path%>
```

show html

```
<p><%= image_tag @contact.image.url(:thumb) %></p> <p><%= @contact.firstname %> <%= @contact.surname %></p> <p><%= @contact.phone %></p> <p><%= @contact.email %></p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> <%= link_to 'Remove', contact_path(@contact), method: :delete %><br /><br /> <%= link_to 'Contacts', contacts_path %>
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160504125849) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database   enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "surname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"   end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false   end
```

Answer (score 1):

> When logging in as two different users each should only see their own
>   contacts however currently users sees all the same contacts

The problem is with this line `@contacts = Contact.all`. It holds all the contacts. As you want to display only the *current_user*'s contacts, you just need it to below

```
@contacts = current_user.contacts
```

> ActionView::Template::Error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column
>   contacts.user_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM
>   "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" ... ^ : SELECT 1 AS one FROM
>   "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1

It seems the `contacts` table doesn't have `user_id` column. Create a new migration to add the same and do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: thanks for the revert. Updated the code but has thrown new error  `Failure/Error: <% if @contacts.any? %>
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column contacts.user_id does not exist
       LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" ...
                                                      ^
       : SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1`

Comment: @blastoff Updated my answer

Comment: Anyone has any ideas??  Have checked both data tables in psql (user, contact) each contains an id column. Still getting the error                    Failure/Error: <% if @contacts.any? %> ActionView::Template::Error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column contacts.user_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" ... ^ : SELECT 1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1

Comment: @blastoff Did't you get my answer? You need to add `user_id` to `contacts` table.

Comment: hi yes, but thought as belongs_to and has_many were on models that they automatically updated the database (now i know it doesn't...and have to adjust the table and remigrate....doh!). Have had to add this ``current_user.contacts.create(contact_params)`` to the create method in index.html as well, before it was ``Contacts.create(contact_params)`` and was causing further errors. Tks for the revert Pavan! Will now try and set up a one to one conversation, this could take a while :)